# GT-P5100 boot loop - nothing helps

Tags: boot-loop

OK. I have tried nearly everything recommended on this site and on xda-developers to fix this boot loop issue, and nothing works.
This is a standard unlocked GT-P5100 running 4.0.3. It was running fine and then one day it started to boot loop. It was never used much, and it basically spasmed sometime around a year ago.
I have tried:

Deleting cache and factory reset from various mechanisms. They generally say that they work, but don't actually delete anything.

Using ODIN to install TWRP said it had succeeded, but nothing actually changed.

Using ODIN to install CWM said it had succeeded, but nothing actually changed.

I tried various rooters, Kingoroot being the last. It said it had worked, but I see no evidence of that
.
I successfully (apparently) rooted it via ODIN, but again, there's no evidence of that.

Flashing a new version with ODIN gives me the message:  "Complete(Write) operation failed.
 All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)"

I tried to re-flash the same version but nothing changed.
I managed to get an actual upgrade to a later version of Android flashed once, according to ODIN, but when  I checked I was still on 4.0.3.

Some issues that make it more difficult:

The re-boot cycle can be as short as 10 seconds, so I often have no time to do much. In upload mode it seems to last for as like as I like.

Changes I make don't stick. I can set the USB debugging switch on, but after the next re-boot it's gone. I have tried deleting apps, e.g. Chrome, to free up space, I shouldn't need to, of course, as I have about 8Gb free. I never succeed in deleting anything, although I get an Application Deleted message, and then an immediate re-boot.

So it looks to me as though something is smelly in my RAM.

There is nothing I need to keep, my wife just uses the toy to google the news while we are travelling, so if there's anything radidal I can do, by, for example running something brutal from the SD card, I would be happy to do it.

So. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have tried everything using various flashing methods, so possibly your problem lies elsewhere (hardware).
If your problem is rebooting loop, then it has to do with your power button being messed up...
Try taking the phone apart carefully (if you know how)
Then hold the power panel down for some seconds (like 15-20seconds). Note: Do this when the phone switch off before it restart.

But if your problem is the phone being stuck on boot loop, then flash using sp flash tool with your phone firmware.
Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Benuloh. Tried that. It's still looping. The SP Flash Tool only seems to be for a limited number of devices.I cannot make it work with the GT-P5100.

Comment: I also tried the risky process of ticking the re-partition option in ODIN while trying to re-flash. That did nothing.

Comment: Elsewhere someone recommended to wipe it all and use Kies to restore it to stock. I don't know how to do this, but I will google it and if it works say so here.

Answer (score 0):

News. Eventually, after all of the various tricks, I transplanted a new Mobo in, and it works, thus demonstrating that the RAM was forked.